# Automatically filling in 0 and 0% in Excel blank cells

Tags: excel-2007

I am trying to automatically enter 0 and 0% values in blank cells in Excel. I have a report in Excel that gets automatically filled up from [SAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAS_%28software%29). After I save this report, I want the blank cells get automatically filled as 0 in numeric columns and 0% in percent columns.

What would the macro or VBA code be for that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you just want to add 0 to a blank cell, there are several ways to do that - here's one using range A1:D10 as an example. Note that if a cell is formatted as percentage, the "%" is automatically appended to the 0. :

```
Sub test()

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("A1:D10")
    If Len(cell.Value) = 0 Then
        cell.Value = 0
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Please note that if you are doing this on a large range of cells (actually it's good practice to do this all the time), you want to make sure you add `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the start of the code and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end. That will make it run much faster.

Comment: also `If Len(Trim(cell.Value)) = 0 Then` There can be some white spaces also possible.

Answer (score 4):

If the cells are truly blank (ie empty) then there are two ways to fill the cells immediately using `SpecialCells`, either manually, or with quick code avoiding loops.

David Mcritchie has written this up in detail [here](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/fillempt.htm).

*manual route*

- Make a selection
- Press`F5` ... Special .. Goto blanks
- in the formula bar add `0`
- then press `Ctrl` + `Enter`

*code route*

```
Sub Quickfull()
'reset usedrange
ActiveSheet.UsedRange
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlBlanks).Value = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Please note that special cells will only return cells inside a used range. If there are no used cells, SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) will return an error (no cells found).